# seed images using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am trying to create a Angular 4 app that uses a rails API to display and upload images. to upload images using the rails API I have decided to use carrierwave. what I would like to know is how do I seed some initial images and store the url in the database? below is what I have done in my db.seed file

```
Pictures.create!(
    image: Rails.root.join("C:/Ciaran/admin/src/assets/images/test_img1.jpg").open,
)
```

However where is the image stored in my rails app folder? I do not see it anywhere.

And when I inspect the pictures table in MySQL for the image column the whole url is not displayed only test_img1.jpg? How do I make it show the full url?

So basically if someone who knows more about rails and carrierwave could please explain to me:

1. For the code snippet that I have shown above does that create a copy of the image into my rails app? because I do not see it in any of the apps folders once I have seeded the database?
2. why is the full url not displayed in the database table for pictures and how do I get it to display the full url so I can access it from my angular front end?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

1 - in your app folder there should be a file called image_uploader.rb. And it should have a `def store_dir` which indicates where is your files are stored.

2 - because full url is generated based on the above image_uploader.rb configuration file. You can simply get the url for example if your model instance variable is @picture

```
@picture = Picture.first
@picture.image.thumb.url
```